# What is the subReader used for in Lucene?

Tags: search, lucene

I don't know what the `ReaderUtil.subReader` of *Lucene* does. Does anybody know what it does?

See the class definition here: [ReaderUtil](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/util/ReaderUtil.html).

Is it used to read each segment separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Lucene index is divided into segments. In short, from each segment only a chunk of the index is read. And subreaders are the actual readers which work directly on a segment (one segment => one segment reader). And the `IndexReader`, which clients use, is an aggregated implementation that uses the subreaders to perform the actual work.